# PHP Sum from Access using Array

Tags: php, arrays, ms-access, sum

I have a question involving PHP arrays and adding up the values.

I have an access database with information in this scheme

```
----------------------
| time | code        |
|------|-------------|
| 600  | broke down  |
| 500  | broke down  |
| 300  | waiting     |
| 200  | waiting     |
| 400  | remove coil |
```

Anyways, you get the idea. I have multiple code values, but can have multiple time values for one code. What I am trying to accomplish with PHP is to add up all **time** values and only display **one code value**.

The result I want would be:

```
1100 | Brokedown (600 & 500 added together)
500  | Waiting (300 & 200 added together)
400  | Remove Coil
```

Just for example. I think I should be using a multidimensional array, but I just cannot seem to wrap my head around what to do exactly with it. A point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not SQL?

```
SELECT Code, Sum([Time]) 
FROM Table
GROUP BY Code
```

Time is a reserved word, so I guess it is an imaginary name. If it is real, you must enclose it in square brackets, or better, change it.

Comment: Why not [zoidberg](http://www.google.com/imgres?hl=en&sa=X&biw=1280&bih=939&tbm=isch&prmd=imvns&tbnid=nUkwiLPTiVeWRM:&imgrefurl=http://memegenerator.net/instance/22901995&docid=xVSBnBMIHmhIqM&imgurl=http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/400x/22901995.jpg&w=400&h=306&ei=FmYZULafM6S60QHYuIG4CQ&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=398&vpy=297&dur=3977&hovh=196&hovw=257&tx=80&ty=219&sig=111666210613304120248&page=1&tbnh=141&tbnw=184&start=0&ndsp=30&ved=1t:429,r:7,s:0,i:98)?

Comment: You are right, it was only for example. I just got everything working. Once again, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use SQL for this to return what you're looking for.

```
SELECT SUM(time), code FROM table_name GROUP BY code
```